# LabelEncoder object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import argparse
import pickle

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-e", "--embeddings",default=r"C:\Users\osama\Desktop\opencv-face-recognition\face_detection_model\output",
    help="path to serialized db of facial embeddings")
ap.add_argument("-r", "--recognizer", default=r"C:\Users\osama\Desktop\opencv-face-recognition\face_detection_model\output",
    help="path to output model trained to recognize faces")
ap.add_argument("-l", "--le", default=r"C:\Users\osama\Desktop\opencv-face-recognition\face_detection_model\output",
    help="path to output label encoder")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# load the face embeddings
print("[INFO] loading face embeddings...")
data = pickle.loads(open(args["embeddings"], "rb").read())

# encode the labels



   print("[INFO] encoding labels...")
    le = LabelEncoder()
    labels = le.fit_transform(data["names"])

# train the model used to accept the 128-d embeddings of the face and
# then produce the actual face recognition


 print("[INFO] training model...")
    recognizer = SVC(C=1.0, kernel="linear", probability=True)
    recognizer.fit(data["embeddings"], labels)

# write the actual face recognition model to disk
f = open(args["recognizer"], "wb")
f.write(pickle.dumps(recognizer))
f.close()

#write the label encoder to disk
f = open(args["le"], "wb")
f.write(pickle.dumps(le))
f.close()
```

The Error I get is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-f2ad45651de8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/osama/Desktop/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/osama/Desktop')

  File "C:\Users\osama\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\osama\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/osama/Desktop/untitled1.py", line 28, in <module>
    labels = le.fit_transform(data["names"])

TypeError: 'LabelEncoder' object is not subscriptable
```

I trying to label the names and get this error. What could be done?

Comment: Are you getting this error on this exact line: `le = LabelEncoder()`? Yet this line doesn't attempt to index into `le`, nor do any surrounding ones... Is this the full traceback?

Comment: yes ,line doesn't attempt to index into le

Comment: Please make sure that the code you posted here is the _exact_ code you're running and include the full traceback (that starts with `Traceback (most recent call last):`)

Comment: i edit it for the full code that i have

Comment: We need the full traceback, not the last error.

Comment: is that what you meant ?

Comment: No, @ForceBru already provided you a hint to locate the traceback in the output of your code, it starts with that starts with Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: sorry , i did it now

Comment: Does this actually run, as-is? There are many indentation errors, I don't think this is runnable...

Comment: yes , it is run

Comment: So what's in data? Can you add, after `data = pickle.loads(open(args["embeddings"], "rb").read())`, a `print(type(data))`?

Comment: it is print this <class 'sklearn.preprocessing.label.LabelEncoder'>

Comment: Ah-hah! So that's where the problem is, the pickled object that you read there in data is a LabelEncoder and that's not subscriptable. You probable expected something else in data.

Comment: thank you so mush it's run now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unpickling an object here:

```
data = pickle.loads(open(args["embeddings"], "rb").read())
```

which has type LabelEncoder. Then you are trying to access it using subscripts (index, like a list) here:

```
    labels = le.fit_transform(data["names"])
```

That isn't allowed. So you'll need to fix that. Perhaps you want something like this:

```
    labels = le.fit_transform(data.get_params())
```

In any event, `data` is a `LabelEncoder` object, and it is not accessible using subscripts (`data["names"]` will not work). What type of object are you expecting `data` to be?

Comment: labels = le.fit_transform(data.get_params.keys())

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: sorry, I made an edit. try it again (change from `labels = le.fit_transform(data.get_params.keys())` to `labels = le.fit_transform(data.get_params().keys())`

Comment: sorry i take your time but i get error # raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))

ValueError: bad input shape ()

Comment: What data type are you expecting for the object `data`? it is a `LabelEncoder`, and you can't access it the way you are doing maybe try it like this: `labels = le.fit_transform(data.get_params)`

Comment: i got the same error, can you look the next line in the code ??    recognizer.fit(data["embeddings"], labels)

Comment: It's not getting that far. It is getting stuck on this: `labels = le.fit_transform(data["names"])`